# Apache Spark inserts quotations marks in the first column

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

## My Setup

**I'm using the following components**

- spark-core_2.10
- spark-sql_2.10

### My Problem

this is basically my code

```
Dataset<Row> rowsSource = spark.read()
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("delimiter", ";")
    .csv("source.csv");

Dataset<Row> rowsTarget = spark.read()
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("delimiter", ";")
    .csv("target.csv");

rowsSource.createOrReplaceTempView("source");
rowsTarget.createOrReplaceTempView("target");

Dataset<Row> result = spark.sql("SELECT source.Id FROM source" +
                                " LEFT OUTER JOIN target USING(Id)" +
                                " WHERE target.Id IS NULL");

result.show();
```

here's some test data:

source:

> "Id";"Status"
>
> "1";"ERROR"
>
> "2";"OK"

target:

> "Id";"Status"
>
> "2";"OK"

I expect, that the SQL Statement finds exactly one Id and that is "1"

but if I run it, and exception occurs in the line where the SQL statement is being executed

```
2017-03-21 17:00:09,693 INFO  [main] com.materna.mobility.smart.selenium.Aaaa: starting
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: USING column `Detail` cannot be resolved on the left side of the join. The left-side columns: ["Detail", Detailp, Detaild, Detailb, Amount - 2016 48 +0100/1, Amount - 2016 49 +0100/1, Amount - 2016 50 +0100/1, Amount - 2016 51 +0100/1, Amount - 2016 52 +0100/1];
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$$anonfun$90$$anonfun$apply$56.apply(Analyzer.scala:1977)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$$anonfun$90$$anonfun$apply$56.apply(Analyzer.scala:1977)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$$anonfun$90.apply(Analyzer.scala:1976)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$$anonfun$90.apply(Analyzer.scala:1975)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$$commonNaturalJoinProcessing(Analyzer.scala:1975)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveNaturalAndUsingJoin$$anonfun$apply$31.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:1961)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveNaturalAndUsingJoin$$anonfun$apply$31.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:1958)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5.apply(TreeNode.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildren(TreeNode.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5.apply(TreeNode.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildren(TreeNode.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveNaturalAndUsingJoin$.apply(Analyzer.scala:1958)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveNaturalAndUsingJoin$.apply(Analyzer.scala:1957)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:82)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:111)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:74)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:592)
    at MyClass.main(MyClass.java:48)
```

if I insert an additional semicolon(;) before the Id, everything works as expected, here is an example of that:

> ;"Id";"Status"

I think Spark then parses 3 columns, but since the first is not valid it gets ignored.

Comment: What do you mean by `if I insert an additional semicolon(;) before the Id, everything works as expected` ? It is not clear

Comment: @l-cwi if I alter the column names such that before the Id is a semicolon, then the column Id will be parsed as Id not as "Id" - possibly by adding a semicolon is parses that as a separate column which gets ignored, because it's invalid - sorry for not being too clear about that
I just added an example of just that
but thanks for you feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The Problem

My CSV files had a BOM(Byte order mark) included(which I just found out)

> The byte order mark (BOM) is a Unicode character, U+FEFF Byte order mark (BOM), whose appearance as a magic number at the start of a text stream can signal several things to a program consuming the text

after doing some more search I found this problem:
https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/issues/142

apparently this has been an issue since 2015

### The fix

The easiest is just to remove the BOM from the file.

Another fix I found out(see question above), is that you can add an additional semicolon in front of your first column name. Apparently it then parses one more column, but the first one is invalid and gets ignored. HOWEVER: I strongly advise you to not use this, as it might be fixed in the future and the above solution is way more reliable

### A visualization

Wikipedia states, that if I use UTF-8(which I did) I should expect the following characters(in hex) at the front of my file "EF BB BF"

here you can see what I expected the CSV files should look like(since I didn't know they had a BOM just yet), but in reality how they look

since I lack the reputation I cannot post images of the content, but here you go:

- expected and actual content: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oggPb.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Use Notepad++ to remove the BOM, right-click on the file then choose "edit with Notepadd++", then choose tab "Encoding" above > choose "Convert to UTF-8 > press Ctrl+S to save. And it's work perfectly for mine.

My issue with CSV file when using Spark to read, it added a question mark before my first column name. "?[my_column]"